# How can I convert a string into a date?

Tags: python

I have a date that is generated from the user side. However this date is in string format
Here is an example below:

`period = '12-4-2020'`

how can I convert it to datetime format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `datetime.datetime.strptime` method:

```
period = '12-4-2020'
datetime.datetime.strptime(period, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

or (the order of day month year is ambiguous based on that date string)

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(period, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

The first argument is your date string, and the second argument is the string format.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 from datetime import datetime
 period = '12-4-2020'

 result = datetime.strptime(period, '%d-%m-%Y')
 print(result)
```

The second argument, **'%d-%m-%Y'** in the strptime function is called the format. What it means is, it is the date format you want to convert from.

In your case,

```
'12' -> '%d'
'4'  -> '%m'
'2020' -> '%y'
```

For more formats, you can see [here](https://strftime.org/)